# synthesis of zn nanoparticle

Tags: microbiology

Sir the protocol I followed where it has been written... 1st using lactobacillus in Mrs media (50 ml in 250 ml conical)..we allowed to incubate for 24 hrs then added 0.1M znSO4 (50ml) and 0.4 M NaOH(50ml)...followed by a vigorous mixture heating it for 15 mints at 40°C ...white portion observed at the bottom of conical..(.which I also showed)...followed by centrifugation washing it with deionised water again again ...finally pelleted portion collected which allowed to dry to make it powdery form..then it observed under UV spectroscopy by mixture the powdery with  deionise water...
But sir I don't get any pick in UV spectroscopy.. Is  there any method synthesis Zn Nanoparticles using lactobacillus culture?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the protocol you followed? Is it from a published paper?

Comment: Also, please format your question properly. Use bullet points to explain the protocol step-wise. Moreover, add some more details on how you analysed it and what you expect is the problem. Did you try repeating the experiment at least once more?